# Yii on a existing database with char primary keys and dots

Tags: sql-server, yii

I'm developing an application with Yii to interact with an existing SQL-Server database.
I can't make changes to the DB because there are other applications depending on it.

There are several tables that have a primary key of type char and some of the strings include dots.

After generating the Model and CRUD I realized that I couldn't open an item if the key contained dots.

Is there any thing I can do to work around this problem?

Comment: Write a bug report in the yii forums or bugtracker.

Comment: After further trying I reached the conclusion that I can't use /view/?????. In order to open the item i must use /view/?id=?????? instead.

Comment: Can you use a function like REPLACE to change the periods into something else, like an underscore on the front end?  WHERE REPLACE(ID, '.', '_') = foo_bar

Comment: you have to make a few changes to urlManager, to use that type of url, have you made any changes to urlManager?

Comment: In the default config/main.php I have removed the comments from the urlManager component. I didn't make any adicional changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

After some reviewing I made some changes to the default rules on the urlManager.

Right now I'm using the following:

```
'<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

This way it accepts urls like http://example.com/myController/myAction?id=ident&param1=value&param2=value or http://example.com/myController

To keep things clean i also added this to the urlManager:

```
'showScriptName'=>false,
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by commenting

```
    /*'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',*/
```